# iOS autocomplete from JSON instead of array

Tags: ios, json, autocomplete

I want to make an autocomplete with a tableView, for that I have this function :

```
-(AutocompletionTableView *)autoCompleter
{
    if (!_autoCompleter)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
        [options setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:ACOCaseSensitive];
        [options setValue:nil forKey:ACOUseSourceFont];  

        _autoCompleter = [[AutocompletionTableView alloc] initWithTextField:self.textField inViewController:self withOptions:options];
        _autoCompleter.autoCompleteDelegate = self;
        _autoCompleter.suggestionsDictionary = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"hostel",@"caret",@"carrot",@"house",@"horse", nil];
    }

    return _autoCompleter;
}
```

### The Problem :

Instead of autocompleting from an Array, I want to autocomplete from a remote JSON file.

Any idea on I how I can do such thing ? A code snippet will be very helpful, as I am a newbie in iOS development.

Comment: Download the JSON and extract the array from it... What specifically is the issue? Downloading? Deserialising?

Comment: In my case, downloading and deserialising.

Comment: Ok, start with downloading and research. `NSData` can do it, but not nicely. `NSURLConnection` is better. Then `NSJSONSerialization`. Try something and then show code if you have issues.

Answer (score 0):

After making a request to the server using **NSURLConnection**, you should receive an **NSData** containing the following data:

```
["hostel","caret","carrot","house","horse"]
```

This NSData is something like this:

```
NSString* data = @"[\"hostel\",\"caret\",\"carrot\",\"house\",\"horse\"]";
NSData* dataReceived = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

So, to convert it into an array, you can call **NSJSONSerialization**, like this:

```
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSArray *responseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataReceived options:0 error:&jsonError];
if(jsonError == nil)
{
    _autoCompleter.suggestionsDictionary = responseArray;
}
```